# Convert from miles to kms

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to convert miles into kms but I get an error while running the code (Python2.7.13):

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

def value():
    q = float(num1.get())
    d = float(q+1.6)
    label = Label(root, text='the value entered in kms is'%d).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    return

root = Tk()
root.title("kms converetr")
root.geometry('400x450+400+150')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

num1 = StringVar()
radbtn = StringVar()
radbtn.set(None)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=TOP)

label1 = Label(frame1, text='enter miles for conversion', fg='black',relief=RAISED)
label1.pack(side=TOP)

txtDisplay=Entry(frame1,textvariable=num1,bd=30,justify='center')
txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

radio1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text='kms', variable=radbtn, value='kms', command=value).pack(side=BOTTOM)
button=Button(frame1, text='miles int0kmsis', command=value).pack(side=BOTTOM) 


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please format your code and include the exception traceback in your question.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like the problem is `'the value entered in kms is'%d`. You can't format a value into a string that has no placeholders. You should read up on format strings.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about an error, then you need to *include the error message* in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `value()` function you should get the value with `txtDisplay.get()` and to print it correctly append the float to the string using `+ str(d)`

The correct code would be:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

def value():
    q = float(txtDisplay.get())
    d = float(q+1.6)
    label = Label(root, text='the value entered in kms is' + str(d)).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    return

root = Tk()
root.title("kms converetr")
root.geometry('400x450+400+150')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

num1 = StringVar()
radbtn = StringVar()
radbtn.set(None)

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=TOP)

label1 = Label(frame1, text='enter miles for conversion', fg='black',relief=RAISED)
label1.pack(side=TOP)

txtDisplay=Entry(frame1,bd=30,justify='center')
txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

radio1 = Radiobutton(frame1, text='kms', variable=radbtn, value='kms', command=value).pack(side=BOTTOM)
button=Button(frame1, text='miles int0kmsis', command=value).pack(side=BOTTOM) 


root.mainloop()
```

By the way, I think your *miles-to-km-conversion* is wrong but that's another question.

Comment: d=float(q*1.6)this will giv correct answer